# How to perform a search in JTable and display the result

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield

I am unsure about how I can fill the `JTextField` of a frame from a `JTable` by double clicking another frame. I would like that when the user double clicks on the record in `JTable` and closes the frame, the same data should be put in `JTextField` in the frame.

Comment: Post some code instead of verbose (and un-understandable) text.

Comment: Could you please be a little more elaborate? An example maybe? So you have a text field that should be filled with the data of a table-row when you double click on that row, right? What I don't get is the part about closing the frame.

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)  The 2nd 'frame' should be a modal `JDialog` or a `JOptionPane`.  Deal with the user actions the line of code after the dialog is set visible.

Comment: sure, if I was not very clear, my question is this, I've done a query on the database and put a few customer records, such as code, name and city in the JTable. This JTable in a frame B. From the moment that the user you double click on the record of the JTable I want to get the registration code to another query on the bench with this code and put all the data in their fields in the frame JTextField A. Only when the user double-clicking this der want this frame B closes with dispose () and the data has come in JTextField setados corresponding frame B. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Add your `JTable` to a modal [`JDialog`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) or [`JOptionPane`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html#features).

- For single-click, add a `ListSelectionListener`, as shown [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#selection).
- For double-click, add a `MouseListener`, as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8305989/230513).

In either case, you can use the result of `getSelectedRow()`. Note: the result is in *view* coordinates. If you use that result to access your `TableModel`, "always remember to [translate](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#sorting) cell coordinates."

Comment: sure, if I was not very clear, my question is this, I've done a query on the database and put a few customer records, such as code, name and city in the JTable. This JTable in a frame B. From the moment that the user you double click on the record of the JTable I want to get the registration code to another query on the bench with this code and put all the data in their fields in the frame JTextField A. Only when the user double-clicking this der want this frame B closes with dispose () and the data has come in JTextField setados corresponding frame B. Any suggestions?

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that shows your current approach based on the suggestions above.